# When should I apply for Google AdSense?

Tags: google-adsense

My site is not yet up and was wondering if I can apply for Google AdSense when my site is not yet up or when my is up and just a template? Any suggestions when I should apply for Google AdSense and what conditions my site should be in?

Answer (score 3):

You can apply at any time, but unless you have substantial traffic on your website, AdSense will not pay for the time it took you to put it there. Unless you count on 1 cent/month a good pay for your money.

You can create AdSense ads for non-existing websites as well, but having that on top of your priorities when you don't even have a website is not the best thing to do.

Comment: I heard that the Asian sites should apply  atleast after 6 months,after the site is uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

Google will deny AdSense applications for very new sites, often due to "insufficient content."  You should wait to apply to AdSense until your site is built enough that the AdSense servers can pick relevant ads, and the person that reviews the application can feel confident that the site has appropriate content.   Here is [an article that recommends the following](http://www.latesttutorial.com/google-adsense-approval-trick-2013-minimum-requirement-that-should-have/) before applying:

- Website at least 6 months old (an actual requirement if you are based in some countries)
- 300 to 400 unique visitors per day
- 30 content pages that are unique to your site, written by you
- Content pages with text content as opposed to wallpapers, video, or music
- "Privacy Policy", "About Us", and "Contact Us" pages
- User friendly design and navigation

Answer (score 0):

There is no restriction on when to apply for adsense, but adsense will approve:

1. Asian websites only if they are at least 6 months old,
2. Websites that are fully developed (with substantial amount of unique textual content that add some value to the web). There is no cutoff to what Google counts as substantial amount, and some estimations that people put are from their personal experience and need not be reliable.

It is to be remembered that Google won't approve websites that are only templates or websites that are underdevelopment. So if you applying for an underdeveloped website, you are wasting some valuable web development time.

Please note that the amount of traffic is NOT a criteria for selection of websites for Google adsense. But it is worthwhile to mention that without a huge amount of traffic, you may not be able to generate any money out of adsense.

In addition, there is a truckload of other selection criteria that Google strictly follow. [Here is a list from Google](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/48182).